# Aligning 2d Array Print Ouput [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, printing, console

I declared a 2D int Array with some values, and I need to invert rows/columns on the Console.
The first row has to be shown vertically as the first column, the 2nd row would have to be shown vertically as the 2nd column, and so on. 
So for example, the values of [0][0] , [0][1] , [0][2]  should be printed vertically, and the upcoming values of the 2nd row, should be aligned also vertically just to the right.

Here's my code so far!

```
public class Print {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int firstarray[][] = {{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15}};

        System.out.println("This is the inverted array");
        display(firstarray);

    }

public static void display (int x[][]){
    for(int row=0; row<x.length; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column<x[row].length; column++){
            System.out.println(x[row][column] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }   
}   
}
```

Current Output(Not aligned properly):

```
This is the inverted array
8   
9   
10  
11  

12  
13  
14  
15
```

Correct output should be:

```
This is the inverted array
8,12    
9,13    
10,14   
11,15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your for loop,

```
    for(int row=0; row<1; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column<x[row].length; column++){
            System.out.println(x[row][column] + "\t"+x[row+1][column] );
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

into below this will work even you have 5000 rows,

```
     for(int row=0; row<x.length-1; row++){
        for (int column = 0; column < x.length; column++) {
            System.out.print(x[column][row] + "\t" );   
            }
            System.out.println();       
      }
```

Comment: Thank you! But what do I do on the first for loop(rows), if i have declared a big 2d Array(lets say over 5000 rows)?

Comment: Almost there! Now if I declare         int firstarray[][] = {{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15},{1,2,3},{15,88,99}};
I wouldn't be shown the last 2 rows on the output. I  guess I need o use somekind of dynamic variable, since I will have to use later different arrays(with different declarations)

Answer (score 0):

You just change the limit on how many rows you're scanning through: You can create a preset number, (as I have) :

```
public class Print {

public static int myBigInt;

public Print() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    myBigInt = 5000;
    int myArray[][] = new int[myBigInt][myBigInt];

    for (int i = 0; i < myBigInt - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myBigInt - 1; j++) {
            int x = (int) (Math.random() * (50));
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * (30) / 2);
            myArray[i][j] = (x + ((x) + (y * 4)) / 2) + (y + ((x * 7) + (y)) / 2);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("This is the inverted array");
    display(myArray);
}

public static void display(int x[][]) {
    for (int row = 0; row < myBigInt - 1; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.println(x[row][column] + "\t" + x[row + 1][column]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

}

or even go so far as to generate a random number for the limit, like:

```
myBigInt = (int) (Math.random() * (500));
```

This way, you can change the size of your array, without having to change anything else.

I got a little stupid on the random number generator, but this will print out 4999 sets of 5000 numbers in a side by side array.